# Visual Studio (or GIT) is always showing a DLL as a modified file every time I build

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio with Git as source control. Suddenly, every time I build the solution, I have a DLL and associated pdb always showing up as modified files when I do a "git status". If I undo and rebuild, they reappear as modified files.

I am not modifying any code related to these files, so why is it doing this?

Comment: Can you exclude them from tracking?

Comment: Not if I make changes to the code.